# Assembly instruction

Tags: assembly, mov

I'm doing the bomblab, and I came across the assembly command

`mov 0x402e20(,%rdx,4),%edx`

I would think this multiplies `4*rdx` and adds the sum to `0x402e20` (which is apparently not a register), but when `rdx` is `1`, the `edx` produced is `10`, and when the `rdx` is `2`, the `edx` produced is `6`. What operations are being performed?

Comment: `0x402e20(,%rdx,4)` is a memory operand, so yes that is 0x402e20 + (rdx * 4). The part you have missed is that with a _MOV_ instruction (with a source memory operand) the value being placed in %edx (a 32-bit register) is the 32-bit value stored at memory location 0x402e20 + (rdx * 4).

Comment: Thank you. So it does not store the value itself, but rather what is at a memory location with the calculated value.

Comment: @Bob - There is another instruction `LEA` for only loading the address.

Comment: @BobJohnson Exactly.